# Pagination in Vf Page without controller class

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to perform a pagination in VF page without any help of controller class. I am displaying articles in salesforce. There is  tag i have hasmorevar attribute. how can i use it.

Comment: Can you try to elaborate a bit more?  It's very hard to tell exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of this attribute ? It could for instance clear up your question if  you quote the documentation (and sample) and explain us what you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a counter of some kind in order to do what you're asking. Since you can't use JavaScript in a PDF, the counter is put in the controller and done as below:

```
@page {

@top-right {
content: "Page " counter(page);
}
}
```

Comment: Answer is here.    http://discoveryofmind.blogspot.in/p/pagination-in-knowledge-article-in.html

Comment: Thought your original question included rendering as a PDF. Including JS for pagination counter and breaks is an entirely different matter.